# Why grepl ingore.case doesn't work with latin words?

Tags: regex, r

I'm cleaning strings of characters that contain names. I don't understand why `grepl` `ingnore.case` do not work, whereas in `gsub` it does. Here is an example:

```
x <-c("castañda", "gonzález", "gonzÁlez", "gonzález")
> grepl("á", x, ignore.case = T)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Here `grepl` is not matching "gonzÁlez"

```
gsub("á", x=x, "a", ignore.case = T)
[1] "castañda" "gonzalez" "gonzalez" "gonzalez"
```

Whereas `gsub` succesfuly matches "á" and "Á"

Comment: I tried your grepl and it works fine for me by returning: `[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE`. I also tried `tolower(x)` and it converts Á to á succesfully.

Comment: Where do you code in? You might need to set correct locale. Also, check if those a symbols are the same in both limes of code.

Comment: Hi, I'm coding in Linux Mint 18, How can I check if those symbols are the same? Visible the look the same, just one upper and the other lowercase.